# Java Ebean Create Table Manually

Tags: java, ebean, playframework-2.5

Can I run a raw MySQL query with Java using ebean? I want to run this query everytime a form is submitted:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `custom_{table}` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_name` varchar(24),
`provider_id` int(11),
`is_active` tinyint(1),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

where `{table}` is from a submitted form.

If creating a MySQL specific query and make Java execute it, any alternatives that I can do to create this custom table?

I'm using Play framework btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use simply JDBC to create the tables and to query on the tables you would need to used ebean rawSql as your tables wont be registered beans on ebean server

RawSql : http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/query/features#rawsql